# Selecting specific variables from a larger dataframe

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to figure out why I am getting an error using the plyr select() function. I have a large spreadsheet that I import into R and it has around 7000 observations of 55 variables. I want to grab all observations for variables 2, 1, 4, 5, and 16. This will eventually grow once I figure out my error.
The data comes into R just fine and I can view the original file. I then create a new dataframe and then rename the needed variables. I have verified that up to this point my script works fine. It is at the point I am creating a new dataframe using the select() function where my error - could not find function "select" is returned. Here is my code:

```
library(readr)
require(plyr)
AIS <- read_csv("AIS_Workforce_20201012.csv", 
                               na = "empty")
#View(AIS)

## Create the Salesforce Import File

## **Rename needed fields**

ais <- data.frame(AIS)

names(ais)[names(ais)=="Student.ID"] <- "Contact: StudentID"
names(ais)[names(ais)=="ChicagoID"] <- "Contact: ChicagoID"
names(ais)[names(ais)=="First.Name"] <- "Contact: First Name"
names(ais)[names(ais)=="Last.Name"] <- "Contact: Last Name"
names(ais)[names(ais)=="Email"] <- "Contact: Email"

## **Reorder fields**

aisnew <- select(ais, 2, 1, 4, 5, 16)
```

While I am sure there are much better ways to get a new dataframe using the needed 5 variables I am interested why the select() is not being recognized.

Thank you for any recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

There is no function `select` in the `plyr` package. Thus the error. Perhaps you are thinking of the `dplyr` package?

Here is an example with the `mtcars` data, since I don't have yours.

```
library(dplyr)
select(mtcars, 1, 3, 4, 6)
                     mpg  disp  hp    wt
Mazda RX4           21.0 160.0 110 2.620
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0 160.0 110 2.875
Datsun 710          22.8 108.0  93 2.320
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4 258.0 110 3.215
Hornet Sportabout   18.7 360.0 175 3.440
Valiant             18.1 225.0 105 3.460
Duster 360          14.3 360.0 245 3.570
Merc 240D           24.4 146.7  62 3.190
Merc 230            22.8 140.8  95 3.150
Merc 280            19.2 167.6 123 3.440
Merc 280C           17.8 167.6 123 3.440
Merc 450SE          16.4 275.8 180 4.070
Merc 450SL          17.3 275.8 180 3.730
Merc 450SLC         15.2 275.8 180 3.780
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4 472.0 205 5.250
Lincoln Continental 10.4 460.0 215 5.424
Chrysler Imperial   14.7 440.0 230 5.345
Fiat 128            32.4  78.7  66 2.200
Honda Civic         30.4  75.7  52 1.615
Toyota Corolla      33.9  71.1  65 1.835
Toyota Corona       21.5 120.1  97 2.465
Dodge Challenger    15.5 318.0 150 3.520
AMC Javelin         15.2 304.0 150 3.435
Camaro Z28          13.3 350.0 245 3.840
Pontiac Firebird    19.2 400.0 175 3.845
Fiat X1-9           27.3  79.0  66 1.935
Porsche 914-2       26.0 120.3  91 2.140
Lotus Europa        30.4  95.1 113 1.513
Ford Pantera L      15.8 351.0 264 3.170
Ferrari Dino        19.7 145.0 175 2.770
Maserati Bora       15.0 301.0 335 3.570
Volvo 142E          21.4 121.0 109 2.780
```